# RoR: Validate non-model field before create controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to validate a field before the create method

In my _form.html.erb I have two models, one is the owner model, and the other is a model I create to have other arguments, I need to validate those arguments before getting in the create method, I can use an if, but it is not the best practice to do it.

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  #read the city name, since this is requested by city name (string) and it shoud be "id" in the system
  city = city_params()
  @customer.city_id = City.find_by(name: city["name"]).id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @customer }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I need to validate the the city name, because the customer owner must have the city_id, and the _form requests the name (string), so I need to find the city but previously I need to validate the city name has a value and it exists,

How can I validate this in the model  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would start out by keeping all of this logic in the controller and use a filter to find the city:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_city, only: [:create, :update]

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    #read the city name, since this is requested by city name (string) and it shoud be "id" in the system
    @customer.city_id = @city.try(:id) # This returns `nil` if the city was not found
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private

  def find_city
    @city = City.find_by(name: params[:city][:name]) # No need for strong parameters for this
  end
end
```

Then make sure you're validating the presence of `city_id` in your `Customer` class:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :city_id, presence: true
end
```

Later on, if you find that you need this logic to be extracted from the controller, then consider looking at creating a [service object](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects) or a [form object](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects). Because this is a simple case (only 2 classes are involved), I would hold off on creating those constructs for now though. The controller layer is sufficient enough to handle this simple logic.

Why not move the logic directly into the model? I can tell you from experience that you do not want to mess your model up with tons of logic involving other model classes. `Customer` should not really know much about `City` in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**before_validate**

You *could* use the [`before_validate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback in your model:

```
#app/models/customer.rb
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :city_name
   before_validate :set_city

   private

   def set_city
       city_id = City.find_by(name: city_name).id
   end
end
```

--

**Custom Validation Method**

I think the bottom line is you'll be best using a custom validation method for this. You basically want to return the user to the form with an error saying "City not found" or similar; which is entirely within the remit of a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options#custom-methods):

```
#app/models/customer.rb
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :check_city_id

   private

   def check_city_id
       errors.add(:city_id, "City doesn't exist") unless City.try city_id
   end
end
```

--

**System**

This kind of issue can be handled by simply giving the user options to select the `id` at input; rather than selecting by `name`:

```
#app/views/customers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
   <%= f.select :city_id, City.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
<% end %>
```

I think your method of giving the user the ability to pick a city `name`, and then validating in the backend is very inefficient; whilst giving the user a rigid set of options to select a buyer by city is far more robust

Answer (score -1):

We have something called callbacks `http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html` ..using this we can trigger our required validations in the model.

You can create your own logic of validation like example

```
before_create :method_name 

def method_name
 your logic.....example: validates :city_name ..

end
```

Comment: There is no `presence` option for `before_create`. Also, naming a callback `city_name` is not very clear on what the method does. Your one hope would be to use `validate` instead of `before_create`. You're mixing up the concepts IMO.